# Process each form fields in a form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

I have many questions based on form. I don't know the title suits or not. I created a JSP page and contains a form. It has many fields like input, select, textarea.

First is I want to count the number of fields in the form using JQuery. I tried the following.

```
var ln=$("#fileUpload").find('input,select,textarea').length;
alert(ln);
```

The form has one select box, 3 input fields and a textarea. But it was giving **0**, instead of **5**.(**#fileUpload** is the form id I want to submit)
How to get the exact number of fields?

Next is, I want to get each element in the form and find some attribute value. For examaple I want to get the name or id attribute for each element.

Comment: Your code is correct. Maybe something is wrong with your HTML markup.

Comment: Where you put your js code? Is it in DOM Ready?

Comment: I am using bootstrap and all. Bcause of that?

Comment: @NOX no. I am creating a function called validateForm()` in that I am using

Comment: Have you tried doing this `$("#fileUpload").find('input').length` & `$("#fileUpload").find('select').length` & `$("#fileUpload").find('textarea').length`? What are you getting in the alert now?

Comment: I tried what I have mentioned in question only and I am getting 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using each() function:

```
$("#fileUpload input,select,textarea").each(function(){
    console.log(this);
}
```

Btw: don't use alert, use console.log() instead ;)

Comment: alert I used for now only to get the value. I am not using that

Answer (score 0):

There should no problem in your code

Check that you have added the `jquery` and add an `attribute` to your `form`
`id="fileUpload"` then check

Also, check you don't have any other element having id `fileUpload`
 like `input type="file"`

In your page `<form id='fileUpload' ... >` **must be unique**

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qUJZf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the form is loaded before your js script is launched.
To do so, wrap it in document ready like so:

```
$(function () {
    var ln = $('#fileUpload').find('input, select, textarea').length;
    alert(ln);
});
```